# Why has writer given $x ≠ -1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have given a picture where an inequality is being solved by the sign scheme method. The writer has written  $x ≠ -1$ along some steps. I don't understand why he did so . Please explain me clearly. A good clear cut and easy explanation is highly appreciated.

The authors write $$\frac{-(x-2)(x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}\geq 0$$ and then in the next line, write

$$\frac{-(x-2)}{(x^2-x+1)}\geq 0\quad \text{where }x\neq -1$$

Comment: You have x+1 in denominator at some point so x≠-1 otherwise x+1=0 and you divide by zero.  Autor canceled out the x+1 part but in original expresion we divide by zero when x=-1, hence x has to be distinct than -1

Comment: Do not post pictures of text. Type your question out and for formulas, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format them.  I did it for you this time since you are new :)

Comment: @5xum You edited it wrong: the image shows "$x\ne-1$ and you turned it into $x=1$.

Comment: @5xum can you re - edit the image to make it a formula. I have made the question correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $f(x)\cdot \frac{(x-a)}{(x-a)} = f(x)$ only if $x\neq a$. If $x=a$, then the left hand side of the equation is undefined.

Comment: Oh so you mean to say that the f(x) will become 0 and it can't become 0 because the inequality itself says f(x) ≥ 0 , right ?

Comment: Thank you anyway

Comment: @WorldProducer No, $f(x)$ will not become zero. Whatever $f(x)$ is equal to, the expression $f(x)\cdot \frac{x-a}{x-a}$ is **undefined** at $x=a$.

Comment: @WorldProducer You cannot divide by $0$. $a -a = 0$. The expression stops making sense.

Comment: @WorldProducer if $x=a$ you have the expression as $\left(f(a)\cdot\dfrac 00\right)$. Note that [$\dfrac 00$ is undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero)

Comment: iirc, division by $0$ is defined but not in the number system we use...

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Sure, but this question is about the standard $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks guys . now my doubt is ironically cleared